# Electron autoUpdater is not fetching releases from private repository

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, auto-update

Electron autoUpdater is working fine with public repository but it could not find latest release from private repository.

I had configured electron-updater also to use the github token:

autoUpdater.setFeedURL({
provider: 'github',
owner: '*****',
repo: '*****',
token: '*****',
private: true,
host: 'github.com'
});

It is throwing following
error: Unable to find latest version on GitHub, please ensure a production release exists: HttpError: 404

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade electron-updater to "4.6.5", and set enviroment variable GH_TOKEN

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).